# Spark load data and add filename as dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading some data into Spark with a wrapper function:

```py
def load_data( filename ):
    df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
        .option("delimiter", "\t")\
        .option("header", "false")\
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")\
        .load(filename)
    # add the filename base as hostname
    ( hostname, _ ) = os.path.splitext( os.path.basename(filename) )
    ( hostname, _ ) = os.path.splitext( hostname )
    df = df.withColumn('hostname', lit(hostname))
    return df
```

specifically, I am using a glob to load a bunch of files at once:

```py
df = load_data( '/scratch/*.txt.gz' )
```

the files are:

```py
/scratch/host1.txt.gz
/scratch/host2.txt.gz
...
```

I would like the column 'hostname' to actually contain the real name of the file being loaded rather than the glob (ie `host1`, `host2` etc, rather than `*`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can use `input_file_name` which:

> Creates a string column for the file name of the current Spark task.

```py
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

Same thing in Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name)
```

Comment: is it possible to get file creation date in some similiar way ?
I didn't find any function in pyspark.sql.functions for it.

Comment: If you load csv files, don't use `spark.read.csv("<data_path>")`, use `spark.read.format("csv").load("<data_path>")`

Answer (score 3):

input_file_name() is deprecated for the _metadata column, *e.g.*, "_metadata.file_name"; refer to docs at  [file-metadata](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to add the filename using this? I guess something like `df.withColumn("filename", F.col("_metadata.file_name"))`?