# How to get the correct input_file_name in PySpark after a repartition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm developing a PySpark job that read text files and write parquet files on a AWS S3 bucket.

I need to add a column to each parquet line that describe the source file of the original text line.

I'm using the `input_file_name` but i don't see the correct source file name in the output column. Seems that use the same filename for an entire tasks or for the wrong partition.

I don't know if this is caused by the repartition that i need to do or because i'm reading an entire folder (prefix) in S3.

Here an example of my code:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("s3a://source-bucket/prefix/")
rdd = rdd.repartition(numPartitions=(120))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: custom_regex_parser)

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=custom_source_schema)
df = df..withColumn("source_file_name", input_file_name)
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("s3://dest-bucket/prefix/")
```

In the S3 bucket i have lots of GZ files, of various dimension (from few KB to 50 MB compressed). I need to do a repartition to avoid random memory issues on some Spark tasks.

Could be this repartition the problem with input_file_name?

After that, do you have any suggestion to better spread data across executors homogeneously ? This is quite time consuming...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark load data and add filename as dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868263/spark-load-data-and-add-filename-as-dataframe-column)

Comment: No, i'm already using "input_file_name" function.
My problem is that i'm doing an RDD re-partitioning. So i have a 1st stage that "coalesce" datas and a 2nd stage that compute data's columns. In the 2nd stage i see that tasks put a wrong filename in my "input_file_name" column.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but what stops you from adding a column first and repartitioning later? IIRC `input_file_name()` only pertains to partitions created via `DataSource`, and I would expect it to return NULL or blanks after a shuffle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a new column in data frame while reading the data itself.

```
var df1 = sc.textFile("s3://xxxx/xxx/*").toDF().withColumn("filename", input_file_name)
```

In your code, I see two issues

```
df = df..withColumn("source_file_name", input_file_name)
```

- You have two ".", which is a syntax error.
- More importantly, you have already repartitioned the data and have lost the original partition information.