# How to fetch file path dynamically using pyspark

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have multiple files in my folder , i want to pattern match if any file is present , if that file is present then store the variable with whole file path.

how to achieve this in pyspark

Comment: [`input_file_name`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark load data and add filename as dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868263/spark-load-data-and-add-filename-as-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store the whole path in a variable, you can achieve this with a combination of `dbutils` and Regular expression pattern matching.

- We can use `dbutils.fs.ls(path)` to return the list of files present in a folder (*storage account or DBFS*). Assign its return value to a variable called `files`.

```
#my sample path- mounted storage account folder.

files = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/repro")
```

- Loop through this list. Now using Python's `re.match()` you can check if the current item's file name matches your pattern. If it matches, append its path to your result variable (list).

```
from re import match
matched_files=[]

for file in files:
    #print(file)
    if(match("sample.*csv", file.name)): #"sample.*csv" is pattern to be matched
        matched_files.append(file.path)
#print("Matched files: ",matched_files)
```

**Sample output:**

[image]